# The application exited with code: 255

Tags: c#, visual-studio, macos

При попытке запуска какой-либо программы через VS выдает такую ошибку. 
Раньше этого не было, но после обновления ОС на Mac'е началось.
Подскажите что делать, плиз. ty.

Answer (score 1):

Решение: поменять конфигурацию программы на Debug|x64, вместо любой другой.